# If a word is in a column in dataframe, replace the word with another and make a new row with new info and add to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames each with these column `['abstract', 'text', 'label']`
if a word is in a text column in `dataframe1`, replace the word with another and make a new row with new info and add to `dataframe2`. Do this for all of row that have target word in them. For example, if there is 'beautiful' in column text:

abstract:'123'
text: 'this is a beautiful day'
label:'good'

Then make the following data and add to other DataFrame:

abstract:'bf'
text: 'this is a bf day'
label:'beautiful '

Comment: Where does `bf` come from?

Comment: something like abstract. i want to enter replace word manually.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details and clarity. Right now, your question is not answerable because no can fully understand what you're trying to get at. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas' vectorized string methods `series.str.contains` and `series.str.replace`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'abstract': ['123', 'other', 'more'],
                    'text': ['this is a beautiful day', 
                             'this is not', 'beautiful too'],
                    'label': ['good', 'bad', 'good']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)

target = 'beautiful'
abbrev = 'bf'

new_rows = df1[df1.text.str.contains(target)].copy()
new_rows['abstract'] = abbrev
new_rows['text'] = new_rows.text.str.replace(target, abbrev)
new_rows['label'] = target

df2 = df2.append(new_rows)
df2
```

```
    abstract    text                label
0   bf          this is a bf day    beautiful
2   bf          bf too              beautiful
```